# Generate entities using xml mappings using command doctrine:genereate:entities to a different location other than the default location

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using symfony2 with doctrine.

Here is my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver:      pdo_mysql
    database_host:        localhost
    database_port:        ~
    database_name:        somedb
    database_user:        root
    database_password:    ~
```

Here is my config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: false
        mappings:
            name:
                type: xml
                dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/bundlename/Resources/config/doctrine
                prefix: bundlename\Model\Entity
                is_bundle: false
```

Running doctrine:mapping:import generates the xml mappings files in the following directory
***bundlename\Resources\config\doctrine***

Running doctrine:generate:entities gives the following error:

```
Generating entities for bundle "bundlename"



  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  Invalid mapping file 'bundlename.Model.Entity.some_entity
  .orm.xml' for class 'bundlename\Model\Entity\some_entity'
  .
```

Using **auto_mapping: true** correctly generates the entities at **bundlename\Entity***

**What I want to accomplish here is to instruct doctrine to generate entities at a different location other than the default location**